# Cette pensée / réflexion / constatation effleure mon esprit

Tags: synonymes

Bonjour,

Avant le portail s'ouvrait sans bruit, mais cette fois A s'aperçoit qu'il grince et il se dit que c'est étrange, car il y a encore une dizaine de minutes ce n'était pas le cas. Il pense :

> Cette **pensée** (*) effleure mon esprit, mais je la chasse.

(*) = Il y a encore une dizaine de minutes, le portail s'ouvrait silencieusement.

Est-il possible de remplacer "pensée" par "réflexion" ou "constatation" ? Je pense que non...

Comment: La première question devrait être, est-ce que *pensée* est utilisable ici. Je pense que non.

Comment: Si vous oubliez le portail grinçant, tout est possible....

Answer (score 1):

C'est une pensée, car il se dit cette phrase uniquement dans sa tête.

Une réflexion est un cheminement de pensée. Différentes informations mises en commun pour former une information/constatation.

La constatation ici est le fait que le portail grince, et non la pensée. C'est un de ses sens (l'ouïe) qui l'informe de ce bruit, et après reflexion, constate que c'est le portail qui a créé le bruit.

Comment: Si une pensée effleure son esprit, on se demande: La pensée à propos de quoi exactement? Pour moi, la phrase peut prendre les trois, mais le lien avec le grincement du portail me semble un peu flou.

Comment: Je dois avouer que moi aussi j'ai du mal à voir le rapport entre le portail et la phrase qui parle de pensée (du post de l'OP)

Answer (score 1):

Un portail qui grince n'est pas en lui-même une pensée, mais il peut faire naitre une pensée, à priori désagréable.

Voici quelques suggestions :

> Cette **préoccupation** effleure mon esprit, mais je la chasse.

> Ce **tracas** effleure mon esprit, mais je le chasse.

> Cet **imprévu** effleure mon esprit, mais je le chasse.

> Cette **contrariété** effleure mon esprit, mais je la chasse.

Comment: Pourquoi proposer des mots aussi connotés négativement, là où l'OP mettait pensée/réflexion/constatation qui sont beaucoup plus neutres ?

Comment: @XouDo Parce qu'une porte qui grince, c'est pour moi plus contrariant que réjouissant et donc je présume que c'est la même chose pour la personne qui y pense dans ce texte. Cette impression est de plus renforcée par le fait que cette personne chasse cette pensée de son esprit, ce qui conforter l'idée que c'est désagréable pour elle aussi.

Comment: ce qui confort**e**

Answer (score 1):

Pour ma réponse, j'assume que tu as pris la phrase dans un livre écrit par un français. Si c'est le cas, la pensée ici ne fait pas référence au portail grinçant, ça semble plutôt être le portail grinçant qui lui évoque une pensée. On manque le contexte pour dire quelle est cette pensée.

Si c'est le cas, on ne peut donc définitivement pas utiliser "constater" puisqu'il n'y a pas de constatation. Réflexion ne fonctionne pas non plus, car on parle d'une pensée qui effleure, une pensée qui n'est pas tout a fait encore arrivée et qu'on chasse. Ce serait contradictoire d'utiliser réfléchir ici.

Si jamais tu donnes plus de contexte, on pourrait te dire de quelle pensée il s'agit.

Comment: C'est ma phrase. Avant le portail s'ouvrait sans bruit, mais cette fois A s'aperçoit qu'il grince et il pense que c'est étrange, car il y a encore une dizaine de minutes ce n'était pas le cas. Je vais ajouter cette information à ma question.

Comment: @Oreste Je vois, dans ce cas je suis du même avis que les autres, pensée ne peut pas faire référence au portail qui grince, seulement à quelque chose d'évoquer par ce dernier. Tu dois donc décrire ou t'assurer que le contexte précise bien quelle est cette pensée sinon n'importe qui va se demander "quelle pensée?". Un grincement n'est pas une pensée.

Comment: @Oreste En d'autres termes, on a besoin de savoir qu'est-ce que la personne tente de chasser de son esprit. Le simple fait que la porte grince n'est pas une *pensée* valable à chasser. Par contre, ce que ce grincement évoque dans l'esprit de la personne peut l'être.

Comment: Oui, d'accord, merci.

Answer (score 0):

Aucun des trois mots (pensée, réflexion, constatation) ne semble convenir ; une pensée n'est pas un item de savoir, la constatation d'un fait n'est pas le fait, mais la réalisation que le fait est devenu savoir à notre esprit, donc on ne peut pas la chasser ; une réflexion n'est pas l'impression dans notre esprit d'un simple fait, c'est un travail de manipulation de l'esprit ; entendre un coup de tonnerre ne constitue pas une manipulation consciente de l'esprit. Le mot qui ne peut pas entrainer de doute quant à sa propriété serait à mon avis « idée ».

- Cette idée effleure mon esprit, mais je la chasse.

On peut penser au mot « fait » ; personnellement, je ne suis pas sûr qu'il corresponde parfaitement , on dit bien des chose comme les suivantes.

- ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Enqu%C3%AAte_criminelle_sur_le_11_septembre/7e7rbcRULjkC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22fait+est+sorti+de%22&pg=PA139&printsec=frontcover)) ce fait est sorti de la mémoire collective et tombé tout simplement dans l'oubli.
- ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Chapitre_fatal_%C3%A0_la_cath%C3%A9drale/5LVJDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22fait+revenu+%C3%A0%22&pg=PT90&printsec=frontcover)) « Nous croyons devoir vous informer d'un fait revenu à notre mémoire.

Il pourait donc convenir.

- Ce fait effleure mon esprit, mais je le chasse.

Personnellement, je modifierais cette construction comme suit.

- L'idée de ce fait effleure mon esprit, mais je la chasse.

Comment: Merci, j'ai modifié mon explication, j'espère que maintenant mon idée est plus claire. Je pense que le mot "pensée" devrait convenir.