# Cette pensée effleure mon esprit, mais je la chasse / repousse / rejette

Tags: synonymes

Bonjour,

> Cette pensée effleure mon esprit, mais je la **chasse**.

Est-il possible de remplacer *je la chasse de mon esprit* par *je la repousse* ou *je la rejette* ? Je pense que oui, mais je ne trouve pas beaucoup d'exemples sur Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Oui, tu peux très bien utiliser ces verbes, aussi *je la refoule, je l'éloigne*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Oui.**

Les trois versions sont possibles. Mais quelle(s) est/sont la/les différences ?

- **Chasse** sera plus violent. C'est-à-dire que l'on ne sort pas simplement cette idée mais on l'attaque. Par exemple, on va chasser de chez soi quelqu'un qu'on déteste.
- **Repousse** est principalement utilisé pour quelque chose qui arrive mais n'est pas aussi présent que quand on la chasse. Par exemple, on va repousser un animal qui essaie d'entrer dans son jardin.
- **Rejette** semble être plus utilisé à propos de quelque chose qui a été accepté précédemment, mais qui maintenant ne l'est plus. Par exemple, on rejette le chat du voisin qui venait d'habitude.

Après il y a d'autres mots qui peuvent être utilisés:

- **Extirpe** qui veut dire que l'on va arracher A de B. Ici, on arrache les mauvaises pensées de la tête. Il y a donc également un sous-entendu de violence. La phrase serait: *J'extirpe les pensées de ma tête*
- **Eloigne** qui est beaucoup plus cordial. Principalement utilisé quand on veut faire en sorte à ce que quelque chose/quelqu'un est dans une zone pas forcément voulue, et que l'on ne souhaite pas qu'elle y reste.

Comment: Ah, une belle simplicité. Mais je n'accepte pas que mon voisin rejette mon chat. :)

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ces explications. :)

Comment: Pas de soucis ! N'hésite pas à accepter la réponse qui répond à ta question !

Comment: Je n'aime pas choisir la meilleure réponse, je suis reconnaissante envers toutes les personnes qui essaient de m'aider, je n'aime pas l'esprit de compétition...

Comment: Mais il n'y a pas de compétition. L'objectif ici, en acceptant une réponse, et de dire "C'est celle-ci qui m'a aidé", et ainsi aider les personnes qui aurai ce problème a trouver plus facilement comment faire

Comment: Personnellement, je suis très content quand quelqu'un accepte ma réponse, mais ça ne me dérange pas quand c'est quelqu'un d'autres, car ça veut dire que c'est l'autre réponse qui a été plus utile. Donc c'est plutôt à moi d'essayer d'améliorer mes réponses

Answer (score 0):

« Chasser » est parfait. « Repousser » n'est pas aussi bien choisi. En général, ce que l'esprit repousse est analysé par l'esprit comme n'étant pas une possibilité, comme n'étant pas logique, comme n'étant pas désirable, etc., et ces questions ne se posent pas dans le présent contexte ; il est certain que le portail a grincé. « Rejetter » n'est pas mieux que le précédent pour la même raison.

« Chasser » signifie dans ce contexte « refuser d'y penser », « tenter d'oublier en pensant à autre chose », ce que ni « r"epousser » ou « rejetter » ne veulent dire.

---

*Addition relative aux commentaires de user Simon*

Le verbe « repousser » est ambigu :

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/repousse))
> **a)** [Le compl. d'obj. désigne un inanimé concr. ou abstr.] Refuser d'accepter. Synon. décliner, récuser, refouler, rejeter; anton. agréer, acquiescer à
> **b)** Chasser de son esprit. Synon. écarter, rejeter.Repousser une idée noire, une mauvaise pensée, une tentation.

Ceci modifie légèrement la réponse. On peut utiliser ce verbe mais ce n'est pas un bon choix parce que c'est un verbe qui prête à confusion.

Comment: Repousser ou rejetter sont tous les deux très naturels, autant que chasser. Quand on utilise repousse, l'image est de la personne qui repousse cette pensée *de son esprit*, pas l'esprit qui repousse la pensée.

Comment: @Simon Je ne suis pas de cet avis et je dis pourquoi dans ma réponse.

Comment: J'ai ajouté dans la première question que A pense que ce soudain grincement est étrange.

Comment: @Simon En fin de compte, vous avez raison, le verbe « repousser » est ambigu : a) [Le compl. d'obj. désigne un inanimé concr. ou abstr.] Refuser d'accepter. Synon. décliner, récuser, refouler, rejeter; anton. agréer, acquiescer àb) Chasser de son esprit. Synon. écarter, rejeter.Repousser une idée noire, une mauvaise pensée, une tentation.

Comment: @Oreste Ça ne compte pas parce qu'il n'y a aucun lien ; les gens qui liront une de vos questions ne sauront jamais qu'il y en a une autre sans un lien informatique, mais de toute façon, je viens de vérifier, ce que j'aurais dû faire en premier, et en effet ce verbe a les deux sens, ce qui en fait un mauvais verbe.

Comment: [le lien](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/48874/cette-pens%c3%a9e-r%c3%a9flexion-constatation-effleure-mon-esprit)

Comment: @Oreste C'est dans votre question qu'il faut le mettre, en même temps qu'une explication ; vous pouvez faire mieux : vous pouvez tout simplement recopier la partie que vous mentionnez  sur la présente question, et ainsi il n'y a même pas besoin de lien.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que cet ajout soit nécessaire; préciser la pensée du narrateur n'est guère important.